# how to define or calculate the similarity betweeen two curves as the loss funtion to optimize in the generative model?

Tags: deep-learning, objective-functions

I want to train a neural network as the curve productor that can generate the specific type of curves (e.g. exponential decay curves). I take the encoder-decoder structure, the curves in a dataset is used as input, the encoder encodes them as the hidden variables, and then decoder decodes those hidden variables to regenerate the same curves. The loss function is the difference between the input curve and the generated. But the tough problem is how to measure similarity or consistent degree between the two curves as depicted in the pasted figure. In fact, the curves are permited to shift left or right, which make it the difficult thing to deal with.[image]

Note that, Don't need to consider the points that is lower than 0.05.

Comment: Try taking a look at [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping), it returns a similarity score between two curves and it's shift invariant.

Comment: Ok, thank you!  It's helpful.